# What is the difference between encoding utf-8 and utf8 in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

What is the difference between encoding `utf-8` and `utf8` (if there is any)?

Given the following example:

```
u = u'€'
print('utf-8', u.encode('utf-8'))
print('utf8 ', u.encode('utf8'))
```

It produces the following output:

```
utf-8 b'\xe2\x82\xac'
utf8  b'\xe2\x82\xac'
```

Comment: Output is the same, no?

Comment: Question is important because Perl have some difference https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/08/know-the-difference-between-utf8-and-utf-8/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There's no difference.  See the [table of standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).  Specifically for `'utf_8'`, the following are all valid aliases:

```
'U8', 'UTF', 'utf8'
```

Also note the statement in the first paragraph:

> Notice that spelling alternatives that only differ in case or use a hyphen instead of an underscore are also valid aliases; therefore, e.g. `'utf-8'` is a valid alias for the `'utf_8'` codec

Comment: I might be wrong but it seems that the canonical name within Python is `utf_8`, whereas the English language proper name is "UTF-8".

Answer (score 10):

You can also check the aliases of a specific encoding using [`encodings`](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/encodings.aliases-module.html#aliases) module, this way, which will give you a Key matching aliases as values:

```
>>> from encodings.aliases import aliases
>>> 
>>> for k,v in aliases.items():
    if 'utf_8' in v:
        print('Encoding name:{:>10} -- Module Name: {:}'.format(k,v))


Encoding name:       utf -- Module Name: utf_8
Encoding name:        u8 -- Module Name: utf_8
Encoding name: utf8_ucs4 -- Module Name: utf_8
Encoding name: utf8_ucs2 -- Module Name: utf_8
Encoding name:      utf8 -- Module Name: utf_8
```

And as pointed by the [mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson)'s answer:

> Notice that spelling alternatives that only differ in case or use a
>   hyphen instead of an underscore are also valid aliases; therefore,
>   e.g. 'utf-8' is a valid alias for the 'utf_8' codec.

Comment: That's great to know!