# How to read Turkish chars from txt file in Python?

Tags: python, file, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to read user credentials from the text file. In the password, there is 'ü' character. When I read from txt. It prints 'l' character. UTF8 does not work for Turkish characters. How can I read?

```
def get_username_password():
    dosya = open("D:\\user.txt","r",encoding="utf8",errors='ignore')
    line = dosya.readline()
    print(line)
    return line.split(",")
```

> eyll,eyll

[txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1VsF.jpg)

Comment: Are you using Python 3? If no, consider upgrading and save yourself some headaches now and later.

Comment: Yes, I am using Python 3

Comment: Find out which codec was used to encode the file, and use that instead of UTF-8. Might involve a bit of trial and error. Also, if you don't want to lose characters, but instead be warned when decoding fails, use `errors="strict"` (the default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot, it looks like you are using Windows. You probably saved the text file as "ANSI" which is a windows term for "whatever encoding I think is appropriate for the location setting". For Turkish, it's likely [Windows-1254](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254).

In python, this encoding is called "cp1254", so the correct code to open the file is:

```
dosya = open("D:\\user.txt","r", encoding="cp1254")
```

Comment: hmmm but utf8 and utf-8 are the same thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383506/difference-between-encoding-utf-8-and-utf8-in-python-3-5

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this:
dosya = open("D:\user.txt","r", encoding='utf-8')